# Watson conversation system entities sys-date does not work perfectly

Tags: watson-conversation

I had one problem, I enabled the system entities @sys-date, but when I input two dates(format is yyyy-MM-dd) one time, it can not recognize correctly. 
for example, I entered "from 2017-02-23 to 2017-03-21", it identified 4 dates. Can anyone help? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: What is that you are doing with the dates? Will you be passing it as context to the application?

Comment: The dates were the criteria of one sql. The point is how to identify the input date values.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the input text into context variable and then pass it to the application `"context": "<? input.text ?>"`

Comment: What if user does not enter date? and by mistake he enters something else? IBM does not have elicit slot